# Where are the OpenCMIS unit tests referred to in the documentation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, documentation, opencmis

I'm implementing CMIS support for my client's document database using OpenCMIS. I've been following the guide [here](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/how-to/how-to-create-server.html) for creating the server. This has mostly gone well, but when I got to the section ["testing the server"](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/how-to/how-to-create-server.html#testing-the-server) I couldn't find the jUnit tests they're referring to - the classes where not in any of the packages one was told to import. When looking through the Javadocs they weren't documented there either. Am I simply looking in the wrong place or is that guide out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit tests aren't in the main jars.

As is common with Maven based projects, if you look at the [Apache OpenCMIS Source in SVN](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/opencmis/trunk), within each module you have directories `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` .

When Maven builds the project, it compiles both, but only puts the `main` outputs into the binary jar. The test ones are used locally to run the tests, but aren't packaged. (The OpenCMIS test helpers, however, are built and packaged, they have artificats like `chemistry-opencmis-test-util` and `chemistry-opencmis-test-tck`)

If you wanted to run the TCK tests, you can just grab the artifacts from Maven and run. To run the project internal tests, you'll need to either download the source package, or checkout from SVN, then build. At that point, you'll have all the unit tests available to run

Comment: TCK tests can also be run with CMIS Workbench. The binaries can be downloaded on chemistry website http://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html

Answer (score 2):

I can find more about creating and testing an OpenCMIS server here:
https://github.com/cmisdocs/ServerDevelopmentGuide